# Select rows with certain conditions AND THEN replace those rows with certain values in another column

Tags: python, pandas, parsing

IF 'state' is in '4. Closed' & 'closeDate' is in '2017/3/27'
    THEN change/replace/update 'closeDate' with the date values in 'correctClosedDate' column

[image]

```
     df= pd.DataFrame(
                {"ID":['A','B','C','D','E'],
                 "state":['3. Cancelled', '4. Closed', '4. Closed', '3. Cancelled', '4. Closed' ],
                 "closeDate":['2017/4/12','2017/3/27','2017/4/1','2017/4/29','2017/3/27'],
                 "correctCloseDate":['', '2017/1/5', '', '', '2017/2/27']
                 })
```

Here, I tried locate the rows with these conditions, and I don't know how to replace these rows with values in 'correctCloseDate'.

```
df.loc[df['state'].isin('4. Closed') & df['closeDate'].isin(['2017-03-27']) == True]
```

I have an error saying:

TypeError: only list-like objects are allowed to be passed to isin(), you passed a [str]

My desired outcome will look like this.

[image]

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.to_datetime.html), also was added parameter `errors='coerce'` for convert not datetimes to `NaT` (`NaN` for dates in pandas):

```
#if necessary convert to datetime
df['closeDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['closeDate'])
df['correctCloseDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['correctCloseDate'], errors='coerce')
```

Then create `boolean mask` and [`Series.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mask.html) for replace by mask, last remove unnecessary column by [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html):

```
mask = (df['state'] == '4. Closed') & (df['closeDate'] == '2017-03-27')
df['closeDate'] = df['closeDate'].mask(mask, df['correctCloseDate'])
df = df.drop('correctCloseDate', axis=1)
print (df)
  ID  closeDate         state
0  A 2017-04-12  3. Cancelled
1  B 2017-01-05     4. Closed
2  C 2017-04-01     4. Closed
3  D 2017-04-29  3. Cancelled
4  E 2017-02-27     4. Closed
```

Alternative is use [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for replace:

```
mask = (df['state'] == '4. Closed') & (df['closeDate'] == '2017-03-27')
df.loc[mask, 'closeDate'] = df['correctCloseDate']
df = df.drop('correctCloseDate', axis=1)
print (df)
  ID  closeDate         state
0  A 2017-04-12  3. Cancelled
1  B 2017-01-05     4. Closed
2  C 2017-04-01     4. Closed
3  D 2017-04-29  3. Cancelled
4  E 2017-02-27     4. Closed
```

---

Solution with only strings - but then change `2017-03-27` to `2017/3/27`:

```
mask = (df['state'] == '4. Closed') & (df['closeDate'] == '2017/3/27')
df['closeDate'] = df['closeDate'].mask(mask, df['correctCloseDate'])
df = df.drop('correctCloseDate', axis=1)
print (df)
  ID  closeDate         state
0  A  2017/4/12  3. Cancelled
1  B   2017/1/5     4. Closed
2  C   2017/4/1     4. Closed
3  D  2017/4/29  3. Cancelled
4  E  2017/2/27     4. Closed
```

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer and showing different options!

Answer (score 0):

```
# you can use numpy.where to locate the rows you need and get the correct date for each row based on your condition and put them back in a new column(or back to correctCloseDate if you want)

df['final_correctCloseDate'] = np.where((df['state'] == '4. Closed') & (df['closeDate'] == '2017-03-27'), df.correctCloseDate, df.closeDate)
```

Comment: This also worked Allen. It always surprises me to see that there are so many different ways to solve problems. Much thanks!!